# Mapping image into cylinder or sphere shape?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

So lets say I have black & white image that is read with imread() command and saved into matrix A.

I want to output/graph this matrix A image in a cylinder shape. I know how to draw a cylinder in MATLAB, but I do not have a clue what I should do if I want to put image on a cylinder or draw image in cylinder shape. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

I found this site from googling.
http://www.flashandmath.com/advanced/rolls/cylin.html
This is exactly what I want to do, but I need to do this in MATLAB.

Comment: You can create a surface with an image on it... Using `surf(x,y,z,c);` where `x,y,z` are coordinates of a cylinder (each is a 2D array of the same size), and `c` is the image you are mapping.

Comment: See: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-15PCO/index.html?product=SL&solution=1-15PCO

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The technique is called *texture mapping*. This is a code example from `surface` function (R2011b):

```
load clown
surface(peaks,flipud(X),...
   'FaceColor','texturemap',...
   'EdgeColor','none',...
   'CDataMapping','direct')
colormap(map)
view(-35,45)
```

This example loads RGB image from "peppers.png" and maps it onto cylinder:

```
imgRGB = imread('peppers.png');
[imgInd,map] = rgb2ind(imgRGB,256);
[imgIndRows,imgIndCols] = size(imgInd);
[X,Y,Z] = cylinder(imgIndRows,imgIndCols);
surface(X,Y,Z,flipud(imgInd),...
    'FaceColor','texturemap',...
    'EdgeColor','none',...
    'CDataMapping','direct')
colormap(map)
view(-35,45)
```

Things are even simpler with the `warp` function (comes with Image Processing toolbox) as **natan** suggested:

```
imgRGB = imread('peppers.png');
[imgRows,imgCols,imgPlanes] = size(imgRGB);
[X,Y,Z] = cylinder(imgRows,imgCols);
warp(X,Y,Z,imgRGB);
```