# Using image data from warp/surf Image mapping function

Tags: image, image-processing, matlab

So my previous was
[Mapping image into cylinder or sphere shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475044/mapping-image-into-cylinder-or-sphere-shape)

I was able to map an image into sphere or cylinder shape by using warp function. But now, how do I retrieve or use the mapped image? My problem is I need to use the portion of wrapped image and wrap that portion to another shape again.

So I have wrapped my whole image into cylinder, and now I need to wrap portion of cylinder image into sphere. The portion of cylinder can be a vertical line segment from (R, Theta, Z0) to (R, Theta, Z1) or half of cylinder, etc.

If I need a way to retrieve or map the portion of mapped image, do I need to use different function other than warp() function? Any advice or idea where to start will be appreciated.

Conceptual question: I do not know much about image processing. Lets say I have a square sized image of 100x100. So there are 100 vertical lines, and I want to get the vertical line that is at the very left end of the image. If I map the whole image into cylinder with Theta0 to Theta1, the left vertical line will be mapped at Theta0 with height of the cylinder. Then I need to use the vertical line segment mapped at Theta0, and map this vertical line into a sphere. Then my question is, when I want the segment mapped result on a sphere shape, do I need to map this left vertical line segment from cylinder or can I map it straight from the original image? I am wondering if these two ways will give me different results because of image sampling/interpolation,etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you want to retrieve the image back?

I guess you misunderstand the ideology, you do not need to retrieve your image back. Your algorithm should be like this:

1. Load image (so now it is in one big matrix)
2. Use *whole* image for texture mapping onto one surface
3. Use *part* of the image for texture mapping onto another surface

Like this:

```
imgRGB = imread('peppers.png');
[imgRows,imgCols,imgPlanes] = size(imgRGB);
for p=1:imgPlanes
    imgRGBFlipped(:,:,p) = flipud( imgRGB(:,:,p) );
end
[CX,CY,CZ] = cylinder(imgRows,imgCols);

% Now select a part of image
subimage = imgRGB( 1:200, 1:400, :); % rows 1 to 200 columns 1 to 400
for p=1:imgPlanes
    subimageFlipped(:,:,p) = flipud( subimage(:,:,p) );
end
[SX,SY,SZ] = sphere(200);

figure;
subplot(2,2,1);     imshow(imgRGB);                     title('Full image')
subplot(2,2,2);     warp(CX,CY,CZ,imgRGBFlipped);       title('Full image on cylinder')
subplot(2,2,3);     imshow(subimage);                   title('Part of image')
subplot(2,2,4);     warp(SX,SY,SZ,subimageFlipped);     title('Part of image on sphere')
```